# bash to find non-redundant data across multiple fields

Tags: bash, awk, sed, redundancy, uniq

I have 10 fields of data which contain redundant and non-redundant data.  I want to grep/sed/awk/uniq/whatever to make a non-redundant list.

Specifically i want to eliminant entries which have identical entries in fields 4, 6, 7 and 8.  However i need to reserve one (the first) of these entries.

Heres and example input

> 1, 3972361, 4u5p_1, blb, A, 47, 50, PKET, 1.78, 3
>
> 1, 3972365, 4u5p_1, al3, A, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
>
> 1, 3972372, 4u5p_1, blb, B, 47, 50, PKET, 1.78, 3
>
> 1, 3972376, 4u5p_1, al3, B, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
>
> 1, 3972387, 4u5p_1, al3, C, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
>
> 2, 3972361, 4u5p_1, blb, A, 47, 50, PKET, 1.78, 4
>
> 2, 3972365, 4u5p_1, al3, A, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
>
> 2, 3972372, 4u5p_1, blb, B, 47, 50, PKET, 1.78, 4
>
> 2, 3972376, 4u5p_1, al3, B, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
>
> 2, 3972387, 4u5p_1, al3, C, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6

here's an example output

> 1, 3972361, 4u5p_1, blb, A, 47, 50, PKET, 1.78, 3
>
> 1, 3972365,4u5p_1, al3, A, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6

This is just an example, there will be incidences where just one of these entries will be different which must be kept in the final output.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also awk and seen as below;

```
awk '!seen[$4$6$7$8]++' yourFile
```

or

```
awk -F , '!seen[$4$6$7$8]++' file1
```

Eg;

```
user@host $ awk '!seen[$4$6$7$8]++' file1
1, 3972361, 4u5p_1, blb, A, 47, 50, PKET, 1.78, 3
1, 3972365, 4u5p_1, al3, A, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
```

Comment: I tried but i'm a new user so it hasn't been displayed, cheers

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
awk -F "[ ,]+" '!a[$4$6$7$8]{a[$4$6$7$8]=$0} END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file
```

- `!a[$4$6$7$8]` checks whether the array `a` does not contain a key comprised of the desired fields to check
- If the key does not exist, `{a[$4$6$7$8]=$0}` is run i.e. an array element is created with the desired fields as the key and whole record as the value
- Finally, `END{for (i in a) print a[i]}` prints the values of the array `a`

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
1, 3972361, 4u5p_1, blb, A, 47, 50, PKET, 1.78, 3
1, 3972365, 4u5p_1, al3, A, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
1, 3972372, 4u5p_1, blb, B, 47, 50, PKET, 1.78, 3
1, 3972376, 4u5p_1, al3, B, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
1, 3972387, 4u5p_1, al3, C, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
2, 3972361, 4u5p_1, blb, A, 47, 50, PKET, 1.78, 4
2, 3972365, 4u5p_1, al3, A, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
2, 3972372, 4u5p_1, blb, B, 47, 50, PKET, 1.78, 4
2, 3972376, 4u5p_1, al3, B, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
2, 3972387, 4u5p_1, al3, C, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6

% awk -F "[ ,]+" '!a[$4$6$7$8]{a[$4$6$7$8]=$0} END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file.txt
1, 3972365, 4u5p_1, al3, A, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
1, 3972361, 4u5p_1, blb, A, 47, 50, PKET, 1.78, 3
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sort`:

```
$ sort -u -t, -k4,4 -k6,6 -k7,7 -k8,8 file
1, 3972365, 4u5p_1, al3, A, 91, 94, APFI, 1.78, 6
1, 3972361, 4u5p_1, blb, A, 47, 50, PKET, 1.78, 3
```

or as @potong suggest in comment, shorter:

```
sort -ut, -k4,4 -k6,8 file
```

Comment: Perhaps shortened to `sort -ut, -k4,4 -k6,8 file`?